# How do I refresh menu items in a Swift app?

Tags: swift, macos, menu

I have a menubar app and need to refresh one of the menu items when the user opens the menu.

I have a function that pulls the current IP's being used by the machine and stores them in a variable: `addresses`. The menu is called via `override func awakeFromNib()`. We have a timer function that I've tried using to update the `addresses` variable, but can't figure out how to get the menu itself to update with the new data in the variable.

I've tried using a `didSet` on `addresses` to update the variable, and I've added the function that updates `addresses` to a `Timer` function, but that doesn't update the menu, only the variable.

Here's the code to load the menu:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateProcessTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    statusItem.menu = statusMenu
    statusItem.image = icon

    // get computer information
    let compInfo = ComputerInfo()        
    let addresses = compInfo.getIPAddresses()
    let compName = compInfo.getComputerName()


    // present the computer info
    if let computerNameMenuItem = self.statusMenu.item(withTitle: "computerName") {
        computerNameMenuItem.title = compName ?? "unknown"
    }
    if let computerIPMenuItem = self.statusMenu.item(withTitle: "ipAddress") {
        computerIPMenuItem.title = addresses
    }   
}
```

As it stands, it sets the menu items when the app loads, but that's it. I'd like to find a way to update the `computerIPMenuItem.title` every time the user clicks the menu.

--ADDITIONAL INFO--

The menu class is an `NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate` that calls a `nib` file. In the `nib` we have a menubar with `NSMenuItem` place-holders with the titles referenced above as `computerName` and `ipAddress`. Not sure if that helps clarify why some of the traditional `override func` calls aren't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set statusMenu delegate to self:

```
statusMenu.delegate = self
```

Then you can use this handler to update the menu before it is displayed:

```
func menu(NSMenu, update: NSMenuItem, at: Int, shouldCancel: Bool) -> Bool {
    if(update.tag == 1) { //where '1' should be the tag of the menu item you want to update
        //update your menu item
        update.title = "New Title";
    }
}
```

And the main problem in your code is that you are getting the items by title where instead you should get them by tag so you can retrieve them even when title is updated

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the `tag` versus `title`. That makes sense! However, I can't figure out where to put the delegate assignment. I tried it inside the `awakeFromNib` function, and it throws an error: `Cannot assign value of type 'StatusMenuController' to type 'NSMenuDelegate?'`

Comment: Yeah you need to add NSMenuDelegate as an extension to fix the error
    'class yourClassName: StatusMenuController, NSMenuDelegate'

Comment: Your function was just the ticket I needed! I created this simpler version:

    ```func menu(_: NSMenu, update: NSMenuItem) {
 if (update.tag == 2){
  update.title = compInfo.getIPAddresses()
 }
}```
    

And now I'm calling that function within the `Timer` function that's used to check for something else. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: great, happy that i can help

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    updateWhatYouNeed()
}
```

Comment: Just tried this out and I get the `Method does not override any method from its superclass` warning.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using a class like MyView: UIView

Comment: Actually no. I realized that was probably the assumption and have updated my post. I had some help building the app, so the initial call of the menu was written by someone else. (Who's on vacation of course!)

Comment: ok so at "viewWillAppear" that you can find in the UIViewController call the function updateWhatYouNeed()

Comment: The `viewWillAppear` unfortunately isn't applicable. Because of the way the menu is called, it apparently isn't calling a traditional `NSViewController`. Instead, it's an `NSObject` and `NSApplicationDelegate` using `awakeFromNib` to call the menu.